# PHP - from PHP how to trigger JavaScript to print the label to the printer?

Tags: javascript, php, windows, zend-framework, printing

Using PHP (Zend Framework). But the problem is i have this and it only have Javascript based workout, have not found any PHP. So i was doing something like this.

***Step 1:***

A) PHP Controller

```
class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
  public function fastAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    //$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
  }
}
```

B) test/fast.phtml: Views for html and javascript to trigger

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<title>OnLoad Trigger PRint</title> 
<script src = "http://labelwriter.com/software/dls/sdk/js/DYMO.Label.Framework.latest.js" type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8"> </script>

<script type="text/javascript" charset="UTF-8">
(function() {

  function onload() {
    /*
      "Nmbr.: {$data->badgeid}"
      $data->name
      $data->firstname
      $data->company
      $data->person
      $data->number     
     */
    //var textTextArea = 'BadgeID\nName\nFirstname\nCmpany\nPerson\nNumber';

    function printnow(textTextArea) {
      try {

        var labelXml = '<DieCutLabel Version="8.0" Units="twips"><PaperOrientation>Landscape</PaperOrientation><Id>Address</Id><PaperName>30252 Address</PaperName><DrawCommands/><ObjectInfo><TextObject><Name>Text</Name><ForeColor Alpha="255" Red="0" Green="0" Blue="0" /><BackColor Alpha="0" Red="255" Green="255" Blue="255" /><LinkedObjectName></LinkedObjectName><Rotation>Rotation0</Rotation><IsMirrored>False</IsMirrored><IsVariable>True</IsVariable><HorizontalAlignment>Left</HorizontalAlignment><VerticalAlignment>Middle</VerticalAlignment><TextFitMode>ShrinkToFit</TextFitMode><UseFullFontHeight>True</UseFullFontHeight><Verticalized>False</Verticalized><StyledText/></TextObject><Bounds X="332" Y="150" Width="4455" Height="1260" /></ObjectInfo></DieCutLabel>';

        var label = dymo.label.framework.openLabelXml(labelXml);
        label.setObjectText("Text", textTextArea);

        var printers = dymo.label.framework.getPrinters();
        if (printers.length == 0)
            throw "No DYMO printers are installed. Install DYMO printers.";

        var printerName = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < printers.length; ++i) {
          var printer = printers[i];
          if (printer.printerType == "LabelWriterPrinter") {
            printerName = printer.name;
            break;
          }
        }

        if (printerName == "")
            throw "No LabelWriter printers found. Install LabelWriter printer";

        label.print(printerName);

      } catch(e) {
        alert(e.message || e);
      }
    }

    printnow('1234\nName\nFirstname\nCmpany\nPerson\nNumber');

  };

  // register onload event
  if (window.addEventListener)
      window.addEventListener("load", onload, false);
  else if (window.attachEvent)
      window.attachEvent("onload", onload);
  else
      window.onload = onload;

} ());

</script>
</head>
<body>
</body> 
</html>
```

***Step 2:***

```
google-chrome "http://unittest:80/test/fast"
```

***Step 3:*** OK - result, the print is out

But problem is that, how can i do this whole thing (straight) from PHP?

(and silently cause its a touch screen and print, i cant popup up this Step 1, 2, 3 to the end users experience)

Any idea please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK - iframe can be used and style can be used to hide it to make salient effects.

```
class TestController extends Zend_Controller_Action {
  public function silentAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    $this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    echo "<body><iframe src='http://printing:7007/test/fast' ></iframe></body>";    
    exit;

    echo "<body><iframe src='http://printing:7007/test/fast?input=output' ></iframe></body>";  
  }

  public function fastAction() {
    $this->_helper->layout()->disableLayout();
    //$this->_helper->viewRenderer->setNoRender();
    $this->view->output = $_GET['input'];
  }
```